# Error with data validation and string contruction

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I am trying to add data validation to a set of cells based on a range of cells from another worksheet. Problem is that the range of cells in the other worksheet is not static and can change.

Overall I am looking for a set of dropdown boxes in the A10:A29 cells with the ingredients in them

When I use =INDIRECT("Ingredients!A2:A320) just using the excel validation wizard it works but I need the end cell to be dynamic.

I have this current vba code

```
Dim endrow As Integer

endrow = Sheets("Ingredients").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A10:A29").Select
 With Selection.Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
         xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "Ingredients!A2:A" & endrow & Chr(34) & ")"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

I get a 1004 error on this code.

To make it easier for anyone looking at this the end result I am aiming for in the formula section is this:

```
=INDIRECT("Ingredients!A2:A*endrow*)
```

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this. Use named range instead. Also you can find a lot of article regarding dynamic validation. If I can find time, I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: @L42 is right - just search for dynamic range (eg: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287). As a side note, be careful with `Integer`: it fails after row 32,767.. And Using the `Selection` object is probably not a good idea in most cases (including this one). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: I did look at dynamic range naming but the source worksheet is sometimes completely deleted and and a new one copied in from another workbook so all range naming is lost. That's why I am trying to do VBA data validation when the worksheet and data is changed.

Comment: @MattBartlett Then just replace the reference to the sheet. If you want to stick with your logic though, I'll see if I can try to help you with your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

As commented here is my answer to your question without VBA:

**This Demo is done using Excel 2010:**

From the ribbon choose `Formula Tab`

[image: Formula Tab]

Then Select `Name Manager`.

[image: Name Manager]

Select `New`.
Provide a name for the named range (in my example it is `MyRange`).
Then put below formula in `Refers To`.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1)
```

Press `OK`.
Take note that I assumed `Sheet1` as validation list source.

[image: New Name dialogue]

You will return to `Name Manager` dialogue:
Notice that your newly created name was already added.
Press `Close`

[image: Name Manager with New NAme]

Now, go to `Validation`.
In the validation dialogue, choose `List` in `Allow` Field.
Then in enter below formula in `Source`.

```
=MyRange
```

[image: Validation Criteria]

Of course you need to press `OK`.

**Important:** You can directly input the formula used in the Named Range here.
But having a named range provides data visibility.

Suppose we apply `Validation` in Sheet1 Cell C1, it will look like below:

[image: Validation Sample]

Adding another item or data will result to:

[image: Validation Sample2]

Notice that the validation list automatically adjusted.
Hope this helps you a bit.

**EDIT1:** If you want to stick to your logic, above can be done in VBA using below code:

```
Sub DynamicValidation()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, valrng As Range
Dim valformula As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("C1") '~~> where you want to put the validation
'~~> check if you have list, exit if none
If ws.Range("A2").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
'~~> Below contains your dynamic range
Set valrng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
'~~> your formula based on your dynamic range
valformula = "=" & valrng.Address
'~~> actual application of validation
With rng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=valformula '~~> use the variable here
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

Above code is tried and tested.
Everytime you run the macro, it will update the validation list.
Just adjust the references to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
Offset moves the range Ingredients!$A$1 by **1** down and resizes the height of the range to the number of non empty cells in column  Ingredients!$A:$A minus 1 for the header of the list

```
=OFFSET(Ingredients!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Ingredients!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation of what you're doing, that way the OP can learn from what you're doing rather than just copy-and-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the runtime-error 1004 is because of the  chr(34). You don't need it. Once you fix that you will get a run-time error 13 cause you are trying to concatenate a string with an integer here:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count)
```

You need to convert the integers to strings:

```
    Dim endrow As Integer

endrow = Sheets("Ingredients").Range("A" & strings.trim(str(Rows.Count))).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A10:A29").Select
 With Selection.Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
         xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT("Ingredients!A2:A" & strings.trim(str(endrow)))"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

You can also see this article I've written [Excel VBA, Common Errors When Using Strings](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/24/excel-vba-strings-common-errors-when-using-strings/)

Comment: `Range("A" & Rows.Count)` works fine. The addition operator (`+`) indeed fails, as you explain in the post..

Comment: I get a type mismatch error if I don't convert. Maybe you guys have implicit conversion turned on or something